# using nginx+php7.0-fpm with newscoop cms problems

Tags: php, nginx, content-management-system, newscoop

I've set up correctly nginx, php7.0-fpm and mysql inside an ubuntu 16 vps.
I'd like to try newscoop cms and create a newspaper/magazine website.

the docs of newscoop are only for apache configs, with the exception of this:
https://wiki.sourcefabric.org/display/CS/Install+Newscoop+under+Nginx

I tried endlessly to use those configs with no avail.
Managed to get to the "install" path but when clicking next it doesnt take me
to the "license" page, instead it 404s. I suspect it has to do with rewrite rules as the only error in /var/log/nginx/error.log mentions "...install/license No such file or directory".

Can someone kind enough provide a sample nginx.conf file for newscoop cms?

It would be very useful for others too, as there is no such example online.
Thanks very much.